# Apache2 mod_rewrite on Debian Linux 6.0 issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I wrote the following mod_rewrite rule under my Apache2 server and put into a .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /db/

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

My rewrite module is enabled:

```
root /var/www/db # a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled
root /var/www/db # ls -al /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Mar  2 13:42 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load -> ../mods-available/rewrite.load
```

.htaccess file is enabled in `apache2.conf`:

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

When I try to access my rewritten URL it doesn't seem to work:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /db/user/dashboard was not found on this server.
```

In my apache2 error log:

`File does not exist: /var/www/db/user`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the sollution, I forgot about `AllowOverride` parameter in site's conf, it was set to `none` and should be `all`:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```